# AssertEquals anyOf(object1,object2,object3...)

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito

I have some item list (for example T-shirt sizes)

```
S
M
L
XL
XXL
```

And I need to test can user with size L put on himself XXL T-shirt size

What I need (pseudocode)

```
val allowedSizes = mutableListOf("L", "XL", "XXL")
@Test
fun canWearL_XL_XXL() {
   //when logic
   //then logic
   val tShirtSize = tShirtHelper.getHumanSize() // tShirtSize = "L"
   assertEquals(tShirtSize, anyOf(allowedSizes)
}
```

How to achieve it with Mockito and JUnit? And is it possible or not?

Comment: `assertTrue(tShirtSize in allowedSizes)`

Comment: Why not use some fluent assertions library: AssertJ, Truth, Kluent, KotlinTest etc.